# How to compare nested dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, comparison

I have two nested dictionaries.

```
dict1 = {(t1,name):{('11','22'):{'33':'456','77':'891'},
                    ('121','212'):{'32':'123', '23':'546'}}}
dict2 = {(t1,name):{('11','22'):{'33':'456','77':'891'},
                     ('121','212'):{'32':'123', '23':'546'}}}
```

Basically both the dicts are same. But I need to compare each key in `dict1` and see if that key exists in `dict2` (if exists the corresponding value should be matched with `dict1` value).

Here is what I have written. But couldn't get the end result.

```
for i,j in dict1.items():
    # values of t1,name (i.e. inner key/value pairs of (t1,name)) might interchange
    # order at times that is the reason I used sorted
    for k,v in sorted(j.items()):
        print k           # prints - >('11',22')
        print v           # prints - > '33':'456','77':'891'
        if i in dict2.keys():
           # Here I need to make sure for outer key (t1,name), inner key/value pair of
           # dict2 is same as inner key/value pair of dict1
```

Apologies for this lengthy explanation. I'm not sure whether I am able to explain it clearly.

Comment: What should the end result be, `True` or `False`? Where should it be stored?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing Python dictionaries and nested dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27265939/comparing-python-dictionaries-and-nested-dictionaries)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand what you are looking for but you can use a dict comprehension to construct all the matches:

```
>>> {k: v for k, v in dict1.items() if dict2[k] == v}
{('t1', 'name'): {('11', '22'): {'33': '456', '77': '891'},
 ('121', '212'): {'23': '546', '32': '123'}}}
```

Comment: How can this be used if i have list of dictionaries to be compared for common key values ..?