# comparison between nested two OrderedDict

Tags: python

I want to compare between two nested orderedDict  dict, where i have to compare each and every key of dict1 Vs dict2.

```
>>> dict1 = OrderedDict([('a', OrderedDict([('b', '20'),
        ('c', '30'),('d', OrderedDict([('e', '40')]))]))])
>>> dict2 = OrderedDict([('a', OrderedDict([('b', '20'),
        ('c', '30'),('d', OrderedDict([('e', '50')]))]))])
```

```
for k,v in dict1.iteritems():
    for k1,v1 in v.iteritems():
        print "key %s, value  %s" %(k1,v1)
        for k2,v2 in dict2.iteritems():
            for k3,v3 in v2.iteritems():
               print "key %s, value  %s" %(k3,v3)
```

Output:

```
key b, value  20
key b, value  20
key c, value  30
key d, value  OrderedDict([('e', '50')])
key c, value  30
key b, value  20
key c, value  30
key d, value  OrderedDict([('e', '50')])
key d, value  OrderedDict([('e', '40')])
key b, value  20
key c, value  30
key d, value  OrderedDict([('e', '50')])
```

As the code is quite long, please help in writting in sort with comparision between (k1,v1) vs (k3,v3)

Comment: I'm not able to follow. Are you comparing whole dictionaries or just certain keys?

Comment: @kokeen I want to compare each "key" & "value" of dict 1 with "key and "value" of dict 2.Since its nested ordereddict , so finding difficult to compare

Comment: That's essentially comparing two whole dictionaries. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27265939/comparing-python-dictionaries-and-nested-dictionaries) might be a good start.

Comment: In my case, i have to iterate through and compare between(k1,v1) and (k3,v3) , as my output shown.

Comment: Check the link I've added in my previous comment. It helps in comparing nested dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

### Data:

```
dict1 = OrderedDict([('a',
              OrderedDict([('b', '20'),
                           ('c', '30'),
                           ('d', OrderedDict([('e', '40')]))]))])

dict2 = OrderedDict([('a',
              OrderedDict([('b', '20'),
                           ('c', '30'),
                           ('d', OrderedDict([('e', '50')]))]))])
```

### Perhaps unpacking the `OrderedDicts` into a `DataFrame` is a better option:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

dict_list = [dict1, dict2]  # more OrderedDicts can be added

df = pd.concat([json_normalize(x) for x in dict_list], sort=True).reset_index(drop=True)

df =
```

[image]

#### Also works if the `keys` are different:

[image]

#### print the `product` of `df` rows:

```
from itertools import product

dict_product = [list(product(df.iloc[y-1], df.iloc[y])) for y in df.index if y != 0]

print(dict_product)

[[('20', '20'),
  ('20', '30'),
  ('20', '50'),
  ('30', '20'),
  ('30', '30'),
  ('30', '50'),
  ('40', '20'),
  ('40', '30'),
  ('40', '50')]]
```