# Iterate through list of dictionary and identify similar values in dictionary in Python

Tags: python

Suppose I have a list of dictionary as below

```
[{'name': 'User_ORDERS1234', 'expressions': [{'exp': '"table"."ORDERS"."STATUS" IN (\'Canceled\',\'Pending\')'}], 'users': ['User_2']}, {'name': 'User_ORDERS1235', 'expressions': [{'exp': '"table"."ORDERS"."STATUS"  = \'Shipped\''}], 'users': ['User_1']}, {'name': 'User_ORDERS1236', 'expressions': [{'exp': '"table"."ORDERS"."STATUS" IN (\'Canceled\',\'Pending\')'}], 'users': ['User_3']}]
```

On iterate of this list I want to check if the expressions(key) a sub list values are same as some other set of dictionary key expression values.In the above case users key with value-User_2 has same expression values as User_3 .In this case I want to delete the entire dictionary of User_3 and add append the value User_3 to User_2 list(as 'Users':['User_2','User_3'])

exprected output:

```
[{'name': 'User_ORDERS1234', 'expressions': [{'exp': '"table"."ORDERS"."STATUS" IN (\'Canceled\',\'Pending\')'}], 'users': ['User_2','User_3']}, {'name': 'User_ORDERS1235', 'expressions': [{'exp': '"table"."ORDERS"."STATUS"  = \'Shipped\''}], 'users': ['User_1']}]
```

Comment: does https://stackoverflow.com/q/27265939/13512812 answer your question?

Comment: @coderoftheday in my case I have a single object as list of dictionary

Comment: what name should be given if two expressions are the same e.g```'User_ORDERS1234'```

Comment: name can be any in my case it can be User_ORDERS1234 or User_ORDERS1236

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
orders = [{
    'name': 'User_ORDERS1234',
    'expressions': [{'exp': '"table"."ORDERS"."STATUS" IN (\'Canceled\',\'Pending\')'}],
    'users': ['User_2']
},{
    'name': 'User_ORDERS1235',
    'expressions': [{'exp': '"table"."ORDERS"."STATUS"  = \'Shipped\''}],
    'users': ['User_1']
},{
    'name': 'User_ORDERS1236',
    'expressions': [{'exp': '"table"."ORDERS"."STATUS" IN (\'Canceled\',\'Pending\')'}],
    'users': ['User_3']
}]

for i, order in enumerate(orders):                # loop trough orders:
    exp1 = order['expressions']                   # 'exp' value of the order

    for next_order in orders[i+1:]:               # loop through the next orders:
        exp2 = next_order['expressions']          # 'exp' value of a next order

        if exp1 == exp2:                          # if the 'exp' values are the same:
            order['users'] += next_order['users'] # add the 'users' to the order 'users'
            next_order['users'] = []              # remove users from the next order

orders = [o for o in orders if o['users']]        # leave only the orders that have 'users'

print(orders)
```

Output

```
[{
    'name': 'User_ORDERS1234',
    'expressions': [{'exp': '"table"."ORDERS"."STATUS" IN (\'Canceled\',\'Pending\')'}],
    'users': ['User_2', 'User_3']
},{
    'name': 'User_ORDERS1235',
    'expressions': [{'exp': '"table"."ORDERS"."STATUS"  = \'Shipped\''}],
    'users': ['User_1']
}]
```

Comment: I think it's a most simplest straightforward implementation. With comments for every line. Take the first order, loop through rest of the orders, search for the same 'exp'. If there is the same 'exp' move 'users' to 'users' of the first order. Take the next order and the rest of  orders... etc. At the end - remove from the list the orders that not contain 'users'. It is not an optimal algorithm for a big number of orders, it's a simplest solution. For example you can remove processed orders inside the loop, but it's makes algorithm a bit more difficult (backward iteration)

Comment: I've just replaced `del 'next_order[users']` with `next_order['users'] = []`. It's more durable solution for some cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `enumerate` to get the index and value of each order in the list of orders. `scanned_exp` is a dictionary with the unique expression as the key and the value is the index in the list of orders in which the first occurrence of the unique expression was found. When iterating, we check if the current expression has already been scanned, i.e., in `scanned_exp`. If it has been found already, we extend the list of users at the index position of the first occurrence of that expression with the list of users from the current expression. We then delete the current order from the list using `remove`.

```
scanned_exp = {}
for idx, order in enumerate(d):
    exp = order["expressions"][0]["exp"]
    if exp in scanned_exp:
        d[scanned_exp[exp]]["users"].extend(order["users"])
        d.remove(order)
    else:
        scanned_exp[exp] = idx
```

Your output then becomes:

```
[
    {
        'name': 'User_ORDERS1234', 
        'expressions': [{'exp': '"table"."ORDERS"."STATUS" IN (\'Canceled\',\'Pending\')'}], 
        'users': ['User_2', 'User_3']
    }, 
    {
        'name': 'User_ORDERS1235', 
        'expressions': [{'exp': '"table"."ORDERS"."STATUS"  = \'Shipped\''}], 
        'users': ['User_1']
    }
]
```

#### Edit

Okay, let's make this dynamic. Firstly, the keys of a dictionary cannot be lists (unhashable type), so this breaks our original implementation. above. A collection that is able to be used as a key is `tuple` (unless the `tuple` contains unhashable types, i.e., `list`, `dict`). What we can do is make a `tuple` that contains all of the string values that appear as a value in the `exp` key.

So, you can replace this:

```
exp = order["expressions"][0]["exp"]
```

with this:

```
exp = tuple(e["exp"] for e in order["expressions"])
```

Comment: expressions is a list which will can contain another set of key/value('exp':'value').Since you have added expressions[0]it might not work correctly.Can you update the answer for the same?

Comment: it should be dynamic for any number of repetations in list.There can be multiple set of dictionary with multipke expressions being similar and expression list can have multiple sub 'exp' key value in it

Comment: Yep, see my edit. Let me know if there is anything else.

Comment: will it work for `[{'name': 'User_ORDERS1234', 'expressions': [{'exp': '"table"."ORDERS"."STATUS" IN (\'Canceled\',\'Pending\')'},{'exp': '"table"."ORDERS"."STATUS"  = \'Shipped\''}], 'users': ['User_2']}, {'name': 'User_ORDERS1235', 'expressions': [{'exp': '"table"."ORDERS"."STATUS"  = \'Shipped\''}], 'users': ['User_1']}, {'name': 'User_ORDERS1236', 'expressions': [{'exp': '"table"."ORDERS"."STATUS" IN (\'Canceled\',\'Pending\')'},{'exp': '"table"."ORDERS"."STATUS"  = \'Shipped\''}], 'users': ['User_3']}]` .In this case there are two exp in expressions!

Comment: Yes. It becomes dynamic now that we used a generator expression to scan the entire list of `"expressions"` for each order!

Answer (score 0):

```
dictt = [{'name': 'User_ORDERS1234', 'expressions': [{'exp': '"table"."ORDERS"."STATUS" IN (\'Canceled\',\'Pending\')'}], 'users': ['User_2']}, {'name': 'User_ORDERS1235', 'expressions': [{'exp': '"table"."ORDERS"."STATUS"  = \'Shipped\''}], 'users': ['User_1']}, {'name': 'User_ORDERS1236', 'expressions': [{'exp': '"table"."ORDERS"."STATUS" IN (\'Canceled\',\'Pending\')'}], 'users': ['User_3']}]



def sorting_it(d):
    for n,c in enumerate([x['expressions'] for x in dictt]):
        if c == d['expressions'] and dictt[n] != d and d['users']:
            d['users'] = d['users'] + dictt[n]['users']
            del dictt[n]
f = list(map(sorting_it,dictt))

print(dictt)

>>> [{'name': 'User_ORDERS1234', 'expressions': [{'exp': '"table"."ORDERS"."STATUS" IN (\'Canceled\',\'Pending\')'}], 'users': ['User_2', 'User_3']}, {'name': 'User_ORDERS1235', 'expressions': [{'exp': '"table"."ORDERS"."STATUS"  = \'Shipped\''}], 'users': ['User_1']}]
```

Explanation:

```
f = list(map(sorting_it,dictt))
```

using the `map` function, every dictionary in dictt is passed through function `sorting_it` one at a time as the variable d, so first is:

```
{'name': 'User_ORDERS1234', 'expressions': [{'exp': '"table"."ORDERS"."STATUS" IN (\'Canceled\',\'Pending\')'}], 'users': ['User_2']}
```

Now I'm looping through the the values of key `'expressions'`, `[x['expressions'] for x in dictt]` is the list for this

If the value of key `'expressions'` in dictt `d` is equal to the value of key `'expressions'` in `[x['expressions'] for x in dictt]` then I get the index `n`, use this to find the corresponding dictionary in `dictt` and add all the values for key `'expressions'` together.

I then do `del dictt[n]` since the user for that dictionary has already been added to another dictionary, so in this case dictionary for `'user_3'` is deleted since they were added to dictionary for `'user_2'`.

Also `dictt[n] != d and d['users']` makes sure I'm not comparing the same dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
def function_1(values):
  for j in range(len(values)):
    for k in range(j + 1, len(values)):
      if values[j]['expressions'] == values[k]['expressions']:
        values[j]['users'] = values[j]['users'] + values[k]['users'] 
  return values
```

#In the performance

```
list_values = [{'name': 'User_ORDERS1234', 'expressions': [{'exp': '"table"."ORDERS"."STATUS" IN (\'Canceled\',\'Pending\')'}], 'users': ['User_2']}, {'name': 'User_ORDERS1235', 'expressions': [{'exp': '"table"."ORDERS"."STATUS"  = \'Shipped\''}], 'users': ['User_1']}, {'name': 'User_ORDERS1236', 'expressions': [{'exp': '"table"."ORDERS"."STATUS" IN (\'Canceled\',\'Pending\')'}], 'users': ['User_3']}]
```

#call the function

```
function_1(list_values)

[{'expressions': [{'exp': '"table"."ORDERS"."STATUS" IN (\'Canceled\',\'Pending\')'}],
  'name': 'User_ORDERS1234',
  'users': ['User_2', 'User_3']},
 {'expressions': [{'exp': '"table"."ORDERS"."STATUS"  = \'Shipped\''}],
  'name': 'User_ORDERS1235',
  'users': ['User_1']},
 {'expressions': [{'exp': '"table"."ORDERS"."STATUS" IN (\'Canceled\',\'Pending\')'}],
  'name': 'User_ORDERS1236',
  'users': ['User_3']}]
[ ]
```

Comment: I want to delete dictionary with user_3 value once we add that to user_2 value dictionary