# Compare two list of dictionaries and get difference

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, dictionary

I am new to python. In Python, I want to compare two list of dictionaries

Below are 2 list of dictionary I want to compare based on key which is "zrepcode" and id which is the number "1", "3", and "4"...

**Code snippet is as follows:**

List

```
1 = [{"3":[{"period":"P13","value":10,"year":2022}],"zrepcode":"55"},{"1":[{"period":"P10","value":5,"year":2023}],"zrepcode":"55"}]

List2 = [{"1":[{"period":"P1","value":10,"year":2023},{"period":"P2","value":5,"year":2023}],"zrepcode":"55"},{"3":[{"period":"P1","value":4,"year":2023},{"period":"P2","value":7,"year":2023}],"zrepcode":"55"},{"4":[{"period":"P1","value":10,"year":2023}],"zrepcode":"55"}]
```

**After Comparision, we need the unique list of dictionary from list2.**

res = [{"4":[{"period":"P1","value":10,"year":2023}],"zrepcode":"55"}]

This is the expected output, Now I don't know how I get this.

Comment: here is an example how it could work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27265939/comparing-python-dictionaries-and-nested-dictionaries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```py
list_1 = [
{"3":[{"period":"P13","value":10,"year":2022}],"zrepcode":"55"},
{"1":[{"period":"P10","value":5,"year":2023}],"zrepcode":"55"}
]

list_2 = [
{"1":[{"period":"P1","value":10,"year":2023},{"period":"P2","value":5,"year":2023}],"zrepcode":"55"},
{"3":[{"period":"P1","value":4,"year":2023},{"period":"P2","value":7,"year":2023}],"zrepcode":"55"},
{"4":[{"period":"P1","value":10,"year":2023}],"zrepcode":"55"}]

list_1_keys = [sorted(element.keys())[0] for element in list_1]

res = [element for element in list_2 if sorted(element.keys())[0] not in list_1_keys]
```

I think you do not need any check on the key `zrepcode` because this is always the same.

let's me know if you need more explanation/details about the solution.

I hope it will help you.

*EDIT*

here is the solution if we take into account the `zrepcode`

```py
list_1_couple = []
for element in list_1:
    keys = sorted(element.keys())
    list_1_couple.append([keys[0], element[keys[1]]])

res = []
for element in list_2:
    keys = sorted(element.keys())
    if [keys[0], element[keys[1]]] not in list_1_couple:
        res.append(element) 

print(res)
```

You can probably clean a bit the code, but at least it should works

*EDIT 2*

If you prefer to use some one-liner

```py
list_1_couple = [[sorted(element.keys())[0], element[sorted(element.keys())[1]]] for element in list_1 ]

res = [element for element in list_2 if [sorted(element.keys())[0], element[sorted(element.keys())[1]]] not in list_1_couple]
```

will do the trick too

Comment: Hi @Diane, Thank you for your help. we would have to compare zrepcode as well because in the current example there is the same zrepcode but may not be same always.

Comment: I have edited my answer to provide you another solution which take into account the `zrepcode` attribute

Comment: Thank you, this is very precise and helpful. :)